# Change camera field of view on keyframe?

Tags: animation, camera

I need the camera to be able to zoom in (field of view) on a certain frame.

However, when I do that it effects all the frames and isn't good at all.

Is there any way possible to make it so that on one frame the field of view is `32`, then on the next frame it is `2.07`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to simply add key frames to Focal Length (I don't have Blender at hand to check, but I think I've done it recently in one of projects).

Selected one frame, enter value you want at that frame then press <kbd>`I`</kbd> when hovering mouse over Focal Length value input. Then next frame, enter new value and press <kbd>`I`</kbd> again.
This also lets you use F-Curves editor to specify whatever interpolation of value you want.

Also, I don't think you want to be changing sensor size (though that I would suspect should also support key frames).

**edit:**

Apparently you can't keyframe FOV (I thought it didn't matter whether you operate on FOV or FL), but you can focal length:

[image]

Comment: Ok , its getting late so i will try this tomorrow , thank you

Comment: yup , works perfect!